# React Native: Basic FlatList to render API content

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render data from an API using a FlatList.

I can't get anywhere. I have a lot of trouble filling in the DATA and renderItem fields.

Could you help me ?

Thank you :)

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Results extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //console.log('state',this.props)
    this.state = {
      city: "Montpellier", //this.props.city,
      report: null, // Données de l'API
    };
    this.fetchWeather();
  }

  fetchWeather() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
          this.state.city +
          "&appid=9fce19ee0d267aa48afdf331bb1668da",
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ report: response.data });
        //console.log(response.data)
      });
  }

  render() {
    const DATA = this.state.report;

    if (this.state.report === null) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />;
    } else {
      return (
        <FlatList data={DATA} renderItem={<Text> {this.state.report.id} </Text>} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `renderItem` should be a function. It will have each item that is present in the data array. see https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html. You will be able to use `{item.id}`

Comment: Thanks @KennyJohnJacob ! I am trying to solve it by putting renderItem as a function, but it don't works. I am en beginner, and i saw the flatlist doc. Can you help me please :) ?

Answer (score 1):

`renderItem` prop basically passes each item in your data to the function provided so that you can render them accordingly in the list. Changing you flatlist like this should work.

```
render() {
    const {report} = this.state;

    if (report === null) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />;
    } else {
      return (
        <FlatList 
          data={report} 
          renderItem={(reportItem) => <Text> {reportItem.id} </Text>} 
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your Flatlist.

1. renderItem must be a function that returns all your JSX code
2. Since you already provided the Flatlist with data, you don't need to refer to this.state.report.id again, you can simply replace it with {item.id}.

So your Flatlist should look like this:

```js
<FlatList
  data={DATA}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={(item) => {
   return (
     <Text> {item.id} </Text>)
     }}
 </FlatList>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is that the FlatList will take in an array (`<FlatList data={DATA} ...`) and will automatically go through the items one by one. But it does not know how to render the actual UI for each item. For that we are giving a function which will transform each item into a UI element. This is the function that we are missing.

So

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Results extends React.Component {
.
.
.

  render() {
    const DATA = this.state.report;

    if (this.state.report === null) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />;
    } else {
      return (
        <FlatList data={DATA} renderItem={function (item) {
          return <Text> {item.id} </Text>
        }} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

As per the documentation, what they mean is that this function will be called and each item will be passed into it. The item shape will be of the same shape as DATA[0] (essentially any object in that array).

In the docs, they have this snippet,

```
const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

This essentially means that each object in the array is of shape

```
{
  title: "some title"
}
```

That is called object destructuring, and it is easy to understand if you google for it :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Kenny. 
I tried your solution but I have the error in my device : "Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN"

Do you have an idea to how to solve it ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: could you check the data in `DATA` is an array or not?

Comment: No I don't think that DATA is an array. 
DATA refers to information there : https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Montpellier&appid=9fce19ee0d267aa48afdf331bb1668da

Comment: Oh, then you don't need to use something like a `FlatList`. You can just use a normal <Text> tag and use the data within that :)

Comment: Yes i finally find my data, it is in an array called "weather". 
Should I use a FlatList ?

Comment: You can use the FlatList when you want to render out a list of items. This could be a todo list or a grocery list. In your case, if the weather array is a list of weather predictions, say for a week, then yes you can use it inside a FlatList to render out a list of weekly prediction. You can tailor as per your situation